# Implementing transaction method with invoking business methods in a one transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

Because the `ambient transaction` isn't supported with `informix`, I pass the transaction and the connection through my methods.

I want to ask about three things:

1. Is the following code written well? I mean, no redundant steps and no logical errors.
2. Is calling this transaction method with many `null` parameters in a specific case okay?
3. Is there a better way to handle this problem?

```
 public static int Insert(string processMethod, object[] processParameters, Type processType, object process, UserTransactionDTO transObj, string spPostConfirm, int toEmpNum,int confirmState)
        {
            int affectedRows = -7;
            using (IfxConnection conn = new IfxConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["crms"].ToString() + " Enlist=true;"))
            {
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                }
                using (IfxTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction())
                {

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(processMethod))//business Method
                    {
                        processParameters[1] = conn;
                        processParameters[2] = tran;
                        MethodInfo theMethod = processType.GetMethod(processMethod, new[] { processParameters.First().GetType(), typeof(IfxConnection), typeof(IfxTransaction) });
                        object res = theMethod.Invoke(process, processParameters);
                        transObj.ValuesKey = res.ToString();
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(transObj.ValuesKey))
                    {
                        affectedRows = RunPreConfirm(transObj.TaskCode, transObj.UserStateCode, transObj.ValuesKey, conn, tran, confirmState);//sp_confirm
                        if (affectedRows != 1)
                        {
                            tran.Rollback();
                            tran.Dispose();//Dispose
                            conn.Close();
                            conn.Dispose();
                            return -1;//Fail
                        }
                        affectedRows = InsertTrans(transObj, conn, tran);//MainTransaction --->df2usertrans

                        if (affectedRows == 1)//Success
                        {

                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(spPostConfirm))
                            {
                                affectedRows = RunPostConfirm(spPostConfirm, transObj.ValuesKey, conn, tran);//sp_post_confirm
                                if (affectedRows != 0)
                                {
                                    tran.Rollback();
                                    tran.Dispose();//Dispose
                                    conn.Close();
                                    conn.Dispose();
                                    return -2;//Fail 
                                }

                            }

                            affectedRows = RunAfterTrans(transObj.TaskCode, transObj.OldStatusCode, transObj, toEmpNum, conn, tran);//sp_after_trans
                            if (affectedRows != 1)
                            {
                                tran.Rollback();
                                tran.Dispose();//Dispose
                                conn.Close();
                                conn.Dispose();
                                return -3;//Fail
                            }

                            tran.Commit();
                            tran.Dispose();
                            conn.Close();
                            conn.Dispose();
                            return 1;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tran.Rollback();
                            tran.Dispose();//Dispose
                            conn.Close();
                            conn.Dispose();
                            return -1;//Fail 
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tran.Rollback();
                        tran.Dispose();//Dispose
                        conn.Close();
                        conn.Dispose();
                        return -1;//Fail 
                    }
                }
            }
            return affectedRows;
        }
```

Examples for calling:

```
int res = DocumentFlowModuleDAL.UserTransactionDAL.Insert("InsertRequest", reqObj, typeof(EnhancementRequest), new EnhancementRequest(), transObj, string.Empty, 0,0);
```

```
result = UserTransactionDAL.Insert(string.Empty, null, null, null, obj, sp_PostConfirm, x, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not return error code if possible. If the method fails to do what it needs to do, just throw an exception. In your case, do not return -1, -2, etc, you should create new type of exception and wrap your error code inside.

The `using` clause guarantees that `Dispose()` of the object you use will be called , even in case of exception, before exiting the enclosed block, so all `Close()` and `Dispose()` in your code is redundant.

In C#, transaction usage usually goes like

```
using(var tran = conn.BeginTransaction()) {
    try {
        ...
        // your code here
        ...
        tran.Commit();
    }
    catch {
        tran.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
}
```

This will work well when you do not return error code.

Edit: Here is an example of the exception class

```
public enum YourErrorCode {
    Unknown,
    ErrorCode1,
    ErrorCode2,
}

public class YourException : Exception {
    public YourErrorCode ErrorCode { get; private set; }

    public YourException()
    {
    }

    public YourException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }

    public YourException(string message, Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner)
    {
    }

    public YourException(YourErrorCode errorCode) : this(errorCode, null)
    {
    }

    public YourException(YourErrorCode errorCode, Exception inner)
        : base("The operation failed with error code " + errorCode.ToString(), inner)
    {
        this.ErrorCode = errorCode;
    }

}
```

And throw it like

```
throw new YourException(YourErrorCode.ErrorCode1);
```

instead of returning error code.

Comment: thanks ,i know that `The using clause is an automated way to call Dispose() on the object you use` but if my internal method failed to insert before `}` does the connection and the transaction dispose or not ?
Please explain with code what you mean by `you should create new type of exception and wrap your error code inside.`

Comment: I added an example of the exception, and fix `using` explanation. And yes the `using` clause guarantees that `Dispose()` will be called even in case of exceptions.

Comment: thanks a lot,i return value because i show the end user error message according to the label , how to show the user error message after throwing exception ?